# Reading and writing to and from a Binary File

Tags: android, vb.net

I would like to read and write a Lowrance .usr file. This is a binary file with a particular data structure that I have managed to decode and have written a program in visual basic that does the necessary reading and writing. I am in the process of migrating this software to my android phone.

The Structure as I have defined it in VB is:

```
   Public Structure WAYPOINT
    Public wWaypointNum As Integer
    Public dwLatitudeMM As Long
    Public dwLongitudeMM As Long
    Public dwAltitudeFT As Long
    Public dwWaypointNmLength As Long
    Public abWaypointName As Char()
    Public wWaypointDescLength As Long
    Public abWaypointDescription As Char()
    Public dwWaypointTime As Long
    Public dwWaypointSymbol As Long
    Public wWaypointStatus As Integer
End Structure
```

The File is then read with the following code:

```
   Private Sub btnRead_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRead.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim objBR As BinaryReader
    Dim objFS As FileStream
    Dim objWP As New WAYPOINT
    Dim objwVer As Integer
    Dim objwSVer As Integer
    Dim objNoWaypoints As Integer
    Dim objNoRoutes As Integer
    Dim TempLat As Double
    Dim TempLng As Double
    Dim LatString As String
    Dim LngString As String
    objFS = New FileStream("c:\Binary\Binary File\Binary File\waverider.usr", FileMode.Open)
    objBR = New BinaryReader(objFS)
    objBR.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    objwVer = objBR.ReadInt16
    objwSVer = objBR.ReadInt16
    objNoWaypoints = objBR.ReadInt16
    For i = 1 To objNoWaypoints
        objWP = Nothing
        With objWP
            .wWaypointNum = objBR.ReadInt16
            .dwLatitudeMM = objBR.ReadInt32
            .dwLongitudeMM = objBR.ReadInt32
            .dwAltitudeFT = objBR.ReadInt32
            .dwWaypointNmLength = objBR.ReadInt32
            .abWaypointName = objBR.ReadChars(.dwWaypointNmLength)
            .wWaypointDescLength = objBR.ReadInt32
            .abWaypointDescription = objBR.ReadChars(.wWaypointDescLength)
            .dwWaypointTime = objBR.ReadInt32
            .dwWaypointSymbol = objBR.ReadInt32
            .wWaypointStatus = objBR.ReadInt16
        End With
        TempLat = objWP.dwLatitudeMM / EarthRad
        TempLat = Math.Exp(TempLat)
        TempLat = (2 * Math.Atan(TempLat)) - (Math.PI / 2)
        TempLat = TempLat * RadToDeg
        LatString = DegToDecMin(TempLat, "Lat")
        TempLng = objWP.dwLongitudeMM / EarthRad
        TempLng = Math.Exp(TempLng)
        TempLng = (2 * Math.Atan(TempLng)) - (Math.PI / 2)
        TempLng = TempLng * RadToDeg
        LngString = DegToDecMin(TempLng, "Lng")
        With lvWaypoints
            Dim lv As ListViewItem = .Items.Add(objWP.abWaypointName)
            With lv
                .SubItems.Add(objWP.abWaypointDescription)
                .SubItems.Add(LatString)
                .SubItems.Add(LngString)
            End With
        End With
    Next i
    '\\ Read Routes
    'objNoRoutes = objBR.ReadInt16 'Number of Routes
End Sub
```

The data is then decoded with:

```
   Public Function DegToDecMin(ByVal DecDeg As Double, ByVal LatLng As String) As String
    Dim ReturnValue As String
    Dim Pos As String
    If LatLng = "Lat" Then
        If DecDeg < 0 Then Pos = "S" Else Pos = "N"
    Else
        If DecDeg < 0 Then Pos = "W" Else Pos = "E"
    End If
    Dim mDeg As Double = Math.Abs(DecDeg)
    Dim mWholeDeg As Double = Math.Truncate(mDeg)
    Dim mRemDegS As String = String.Format("{0:##.000}", (mDeg - mWholeDeg) * 60)
    If InStr(mRemDegS, ".") = 2 Then mRemDegS = "0" & mRemDegS
    If InStr(mRemDegS, ".") = 1 Then mRemDegS = "00" & mRemDegS
    ReturnValue = mWholeDeg.ToString & Chr(176) & mRemDegS & "'" & Pos
    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```

Are there similar functions in Java that can achieve the same objective

Answer (score 0):

For the Java only syntax is changes according the Java Syntax,

First you need to create a bean file like below,

```
public class WayPoint
{
    public int wWaypointNum;
    public int dwLatitudeMM;
    public dwLongitudeMM;
    ...
}
```

Second you required File API to read and write into and from file. For this you can use [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html), [FileInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html),[FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html),[DataInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataInputStream.html),[DataOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).